# exporting eyes with gltf to unity

Tags: export, gltf

I was trying to make eyes watching this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfEyhPXsOCM
but but when I exported the eyes to Unity as glTF
the eyes didn't have any textures to it it was just plain white
how do you export all the nodes to Unity at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glTF 2.0 has a specific PBR material model, for transfer to realtime rendering engines.  It cannot support arbitrary arrangements of Blender nodes, as for example a mobile phone wouldn't be able to handle realtime rendering of complex Blender nodes.  Instead, the glTF material definition has a strict number of fields, corresponding to a particular interpretation of physically-based materials.

The Blender Manual documents [how to export materials to glTF](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html#exported-materials).

Comment: thank you very much!